# python win32com.client resize window

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.4.1 to control a Windows Application through win32com.client. I can activate it,I can send keystrokes, click, etc.
Now I am wondering if there is a way to resize the window and set it to a specific position. I can't find a method for that.
here some code snippets, so you know what I am talking about

```
import win32api, win32con, time, win32com.client, random, sys, winsound, datetime

...


def click_mouse(x,y, p_wait=0.1):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))    
    time.sleep(p_wait)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

def move_mouse(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))    
    time.sleep(0.5)

def activate():
    global shell
    shell=win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")
    success = shell.AppActivate("App")

def resize():
    global shell
???
```

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to solve a similar task, and found that `win32gui` from `pywin32` package does the job.

Here's a small example:

```
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Window Title')
x0, y0, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
w = x1 - x0
h = y1 - y0
win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, x0, y0, w+100, h+100, True)
```