# Is there a function that allows PyQt5 to open two windows that fill the entire screen?

Tags: python, windows-10, pyqt5, maximize-window

I'm working with PyQt5 and I'd like to have my ui open on the left half of the screen with a PDF viewer (like foxit or adobe reader) on the right side of the screen. I know that `maximize()` will cause one window to fill the entire screen. Also, I know that I could open the two windows using exact pixel locations and that would work for most screen. However, is there a function that would 'snap' my PyQt application and a pdf viewer side by side for easy reading?

I'm working on windows 10

Comment: I suspect you'll have to use pywin32 to make api calls to resize windows. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629259/9705687) shows how to find, move, and resize windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method as specific as the one you require, the solution is to establish the geometry using the existing methods:

```
# ...
r = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().geometry()
r.setSize(QSize(0.5 * r.width(), r.height()))
your_window.setGeometry(r)
# ...
```