# I want to fix the aspect ratio of a window in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to fix the aspect ratio of a window in PySimpleGUI.

I would like to automatically update the height to match the entered aspect ratio based on the width of the resizable window. I've been searching but haven't found any relevant information.

I tried to adjust the Windows size using Win32Gui.movewindow, but it doesn't work properly.

[python win32com.client resize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616191/python-win32com-client-resize-window)

```
def keep_aspect_ratio(target_width, target_height, window_name):

if not((target_width == 0) or (target_height == 0)):
    try:
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
        
        bar_thickness = get_title_bar_thickness(hwnd)
        
        add_w = target_width + 22
        
        add_h = target_height + bar_thickness
        
        if hwnd:
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
            
            w = x1 - x0 
            h = y1 - y0
            target_ratio = add_w/add_h
            current_ratio = w/h
            
            print(w, h, bar_thickness, add_w, add_h, target_ratio, current_ratio)
            
            new_h = int(w/target_ratio)
            
            if not new_h == h:
                win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, x0, y0, w, new_h, True)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some code example to your question, especially what you tried so far and what does not work.

Comment: The PySimpleGUI calls should resize the window.  Are you trying to do it from a different application than the one that created the window?

Comment: @Mike from PSG Can you tell me how to do this in PySimpleGUI?

Comment: Please open an issue on the PySimpleGUI GitHub and we'll give you a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def keep_aspect_ratio(window, target_ratio):
    width, height = window.Size
    current_ratio = width / height

if current_ratio != target_ratio:
        new_width = int(height * target_ratio)
        window.Size = (new_width, height)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Enter aspect ratio:")],
    [sg.Input(key="aspect_ratio")],
    [sg.Button("Update Aspect Ratio")],
    [sg.Text("Resize the window to see the aspect ratio in action")],
]

window = sg.Window("Aspect Ratio Example", layout, resizable=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
elif event == "Update Aspect Ratio":
        try:
            target_ratio = float(values["aspect_ratio"])
            keep_aspect_ratio(window, target_ratio)
        except ValueError:
            sg.popup_error("Please enter a valid aspect ratio")

window.close()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Could you say more about how or why this solves the original problem?